# Matlab: save diary output to variable?

Tags: matlab, logging

Matlab's diary function saves command window output to a file. However, I want to save the it to a variable instead of a file. E.g.

```
% Default usage of diary: save to file
diary 'my_saved_output.log';
'show this in command window'
diary off

% What I want to do: save to variable
myDiary = char;
diary myDiary
'show this in command window'
diary off
```

Any suggestions that does not involve actually creating the file, then reading it to a variable and then deleting it?

The reason I want to do this is that I process a lot of data on a cluster of Matlab workers and want to monitor that the script runs as it should in this "black box". Rather than saving a lot of log files, I'd like to simply save the diary right in the data structures.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any way to do this. MATLAB has [`evalc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/evalc.html) which captures output, but that doesn't happen progressively.